# SELECT COUNT with two cases query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, case

hope you are doing well!
Let me introduce you to my database.

I have three tables where i'm assuming i should go through for getting results i need.

Here are properties of all tables:

**tb1 - notifications**

```
    CREATE TABLE `notifications` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `notification_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `notification_data` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `source_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`is_read` int(2) DEFAULT 2,
 `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1549 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**tb2 - user_notifications**

```
CREATE TABLE `user_notifications` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `notification_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
 KEY `notification_id` (`notification_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `user_notifications_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `user_notifications_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`notification_id`) REFERENCES `notifications` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1607 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**tb2 - events**

```
    CREATE TABLE `events` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=244 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

So here is case scenario where i want to use for my query all these three tables(Currently i'm using just first two): I'm showing all unread notifications to a user, but notifications which are related to events that doesn't exists anymore are also showing, and those events were deleted long ago, and that's happening because i'm assigning for each notification, if `notification type` is indicating that notification is about events, `id` of event for `notification_data` or `source_id` depends what `notification_type` is. I'm doing that because i need to access those events, but if event is deleted i'm not showing that notification in UI. So problem is that user will check notifications and see counter of 2 new notifications, but there are none, because those notifications are related to events table row which are not existing anymore.

To sum all this, this is how query should look, if `notification_type` is between 8 and 18, check if `notification_data`(id of event) value exists in `events` table for `id` property, but there is also one more case when notification_type is 16 then check if `source_id`(id of event) value exists in `events` table for `id property`.

This is query for reading all user's unread_notifications:

```
SELECT COUNT(n.id) as unread_notifications FROM notifications n, user_notifications un WHERE n.id = un.notification_id AND un.user_id = ? AND n.isRead = 2
```

If someone can give me some hints where to start, i would appreciate that. I heard about `IF` statement and `CASE` statement. I should probably start from there?

**NOTE:**

```
notification_type (8 - 15) id of event assigned to notification_data column
notification_type (16) id id of event assigned to source_id column
notification_type (17-18) id of event assigned to notification_data column
```

**EDIT:**

Here is workaround in php:

```
public function getEvents($notification) {
    $tmp = array();
    if ($notification["not_type"] == 16) {
        $event = $this->getSingleEvent($notification["not_data"]); // required param is id of event
    } else {
        $event = $this->getSingleEvent($notification["source_id"]); // required param is id of event
    }

        // If event exists, get event details, otherwise, just skip it
        if ($event["id"] != NULL) {

       ..... }
}
```

Comment: update your question add   a proper data sample and the expetced  result please

Comment: Well, let me give you an example where i'm using this. Two queries, above one is for showing counter of unread notifications and second one is for reading all notification from database and showing them right on UI. I have set in php if value from `notification_data` or `source_id` not available for `events`.`id`, then just skip that notification, but this case scenario is not the same.

Comment: If i solve this i wouldn't need to do this php workaround. I could just do that with one query, but i'm not sure how could i do that.

Comment: Your question is too complicated for me if you can add sample data and the results you expect (data ... not words or explanations) maybe i can understand your question .. thank you

Comment: Please read and act on [mcve].